# Linker error while compiling Haskell program

Tags: haskell, linker-errors

I am writing a web server in Haskell using happstack. The webserver takes an arithmetic equation as input, evaluates it and returns the result. On the server side I need to cache the result of any previous query. I am using redis key-value datastore for the same. Following is what I have written till now.

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (msum)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Language.Haskell.Interpreter
import Happstack.Server (nullConf, simpleHTTP, toResponse, ok, path, dir)
import Happstack.Server.Internal.Monads
import Text.JSON.Generic
import qualified Database.Redis as R
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

main :: IO ()
main = simpleHTTP nullConf $
        msum [dir "eval" $ path $ \s -> handleRequest s]

data Response = Response
        { success :: Bool
        , cacheHit :: Bool
        , result :: String
        , error :: String
        } deriving (Show, Data, Typeable)

myConnectionInfo :: R.ConnectInfo
myConnectionInfo = R.defaultConnectInfo

handleRequest :: String ->  ServerPartT IO String
handleRequest exp = lift $ evalExp exp

evalExp :: String -> IO String
evalExp exp = do
    cachedResult <- checkCache exp
    -- CODE FOR CHECKING CACHED RESULT IS NOT YET COMPLETE
    x <- runInterpreter $ setImports ["Prelude"] >> eval exp
    let (error, isSuccess, result) = case x of Left _ -> ("Parse error", False, "")
                                               Right b -> ("", True, b)
    let y = Response isSuccess False result error
    return $ encodeJSON y

checkCache :: String -> IO (Either R.Reply (Maybe C.ByteString))
checkCache exp = do
        conn <- R.connect myConnectionInfo
        R.runRedis conn $ R.get $ C.pack exp
```

On compiling the above program I get the following error:

```
$ ghc calcServer.hs -XDeriveDataTypeable
Linking calcServer ...
/home/siddhant/.cabal/lib/text-1.2.2.0/ghc-7.6.3/libHStext-1.2.2.0.a(cbits.o): In function `_hs_text_memcpy':
cbits.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_hs_text_memcpy'
/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/text-0.11.3.1/ghc-7.6.3/libHStext-0.11.3.1.a(cbits.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/home/siddhant/.cabal/lib/text-1.2.2.0/ghc-7.6.3/libHStext-1.2.2.0.a(cbits.o): In function `_hs_text_memcmp':
cbits.c:(.text+0x20): multiple definition of `_hs_text_memcmp'
/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/text-0.11.3.1/ghc-7.6.3/libHStext-0.11.3.1.a(cbits.o):(.text+0x20): first defined here
/home/siddhant/.cabal/lib/text-1.2.2.0/ghc-7.6.3/libHStext-1.2.2.0.a(cbits.o): In function `_hs_text_decode_latin1':
cbits.c:(.text+0x40): multiple definition of `_hs_text_decode_latin1'
/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/text-0.11.3.1/ghc-7.6.3/libHStext-0.11.3.1.a(cbits.o):(.text+0x40): first defined here
/home/siddhant/.cabal/lib/text-1.2.2.0/ghc-7.6.3/libHStext-1.2.2.0.a(cbits.o): In function `_hs_text_decode_utf8':
cbits.c:(.text+0x2a0): multiple definition of `_hs_text_decode_utf8'
/usr/lib/haskell-packages/ghc/lib/text-0.11.3.1/ghc-7.6.3/libHStext-0.11.3.1.a(cbits.o):(.text+0xf0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I can guess that it may be because of different versions of same binaries being linked. Am I right? 
Please help me how to correct this error

Comment: Some suggestions: Use a more recent ghc version. Use stack to handle your project dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two `text` packages installed. Try `ghc-pkg list text` to confirm that. If it is the case, you can hide one of them, e.g. `ghc -hide-package=text-1.2.0.3`. Note: it may lead to some other packages to be hidden too, it that case you can cabalize the code or use `stack` to ensure only one version of `text` will be linked.

The functions like `hs_text_memcpy` come from here: https://github.com/bos/text/blob/master/cbits/cbits.c#L14